# Building Flink application mode without using Flink base image

Tags: apache-flink

I found Flink's application deployment is opinionated and inflexible. For example:

- Some dependencies need to be marked as `provided` since they are bundled within the Docker image or the Flink's base image.
- If I want to change log4j layout type, I need to change Flink client's local file.
- Environment variables and k8s secrets need to be passed in via the deployment command's options, which can get very long.

How do I build a Flink application to run on application mode without using Flink as base image? Ideally, an application where all dependencies are managed in 1 place, log configuration is baked into the app and k8s deployment yaml where env vars and secrets can be specified and the base image provides only JDK/JRE.